# Get Li3 to return JSON results as an array of objects, not an object of objects

Tags: json, lithium

I am trying to utilize the JSON result of a GET request to my Li3 app, but I would like the result to be an array of the returned JSON objects, rather than an object of the JSON objects.

I have the following code in my view file (index.html.php):
`print($todos->to('json'));`

Which results in each row becoming a JSON object (good), but within an over-arching JSON object.

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "One",
        "done": "0"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Two",
        "done": "0"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Three",
        "done": "0"
    },
    "4": {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Four",
        "done": "0"
    }
}
```

I would like to get:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "One",
        "done": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Two",
        "done": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Three",
        "done": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Four",
        "done": "0"
    }
]
```

Note: I've found that this was the case (array of objects) in commit "[974469cf25db5cbab61f3e1ff172405f4635032e](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/commit/974469cf25db5cbab61f3e1ff172405f4635032e)" of the [lithium github project](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium), but with anything after that commit, the result is an object of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$todos->to('json', ['indexed' => false])`, or, refer to the `Media` class for direct serialization of JSON without the template.

Answer (score 0):

`Todos::all(['return' => 'array'))->to('json');` works perfect with `RecordSet` too